# Can elements overflow out of a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have an html canvas generated by javascript (chart.js library) but the chart is small and the tooltips are clipping to the canvas size. I want it to overflow out of the html canvas, is it possible?

I've tried setting overflow:visible but it didn't work.. Does HTML5 canvas work in a special way?

Answer (score 2):

If you can detect the object needing the tooltip, you could display the tooltip in HTML, outside (or overlapping) the canvas element, and layered on top.

Comment: The only problem is that the library generates the tooltip.. so I guess I wouldn't be able to change it without hacking the library itself. Perhaps if I could disable it and detect it somewhere else, but all that is returned from the function is the canvas with the objects already in it :/

Answer (score 1):

No, the default tooltips in chart.js are drawn on the canvas. They are not DOM elements. You have to make the canvas bigger, so that the tooltip fits, or implement your own tooltips.

Comment: Unless you override that functionality, and handle tooltips yourself.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that.